# Unexpected token NL and LBRACE error in netbean

Tags: css, netbeans, ide

I am using netbean7.3 and in code below

```
@keyframes myfirst
{
from {box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #666666;border: 1px solid #444444;}
to {box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #DCDCDC;border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;}

}
```

i got error

[image]

however it can be solved by using `{` after `@keyframes myfirst`

[image]

i just want to know what is difference between first(error one) and another one since AFAIK position of `{` doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your syntaxes are both correct (you can check it [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)) as W3C only define a keyframe declaration as

> [...] the keyword "@keyframes", followed by an identifier giving a name for the animation (which will be referenced using 'animation-name'), followed by a set of style rules (delimited by curly braces).

cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes

So it's most probably a netbeans bug

EDIT: the keyframe declaration grammar is

> KEYFRAMES_SYM S+ IDENT S* '{' S* keyframes_blocks '}' S*;

`S` is defined as `(#x9 | #xA | #xC | #xD | #x20)+`, so it includes "space", "tab", "line feed", "carriage return", and "form feed".

Is netbeans `NL` in this set?

Comment: looks like that is only reason

Comment: edited my answer, can you check if the NL token is part of the S set?